# React extract param from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-router` for routing . I've used `NavLink` and `Route` components like this:

```
 <NavLink className={classes.navLink}
          activeClassName={classes.activeNavLink}
          to={`/brokers/${n.id}`}\> 
....
<Route exact path="/brokers/:id" component={BrokerDetails} />
```

Now my question is - how do I use the `id` parameters passed in inside the `BrokerDetails` component ? I tried reading it via the props but it doesn't exist .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `component=`..., your component will be passed the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props).

In particular, you'll want to access the [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match) object:

```
const BrokerDetails = ({match}) => <div>{JSON.stringify(match.params)}</div>;
```

should show you all the parameters; `match.params.id` would be the `id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access `props.Id` won't work because it isn't in that location.

When you try to access params from an URL, which is passed using 'React-router-dom', then the way to access the props is `match.params.id`