# Url parameters not being shown Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redirect

This is my customers.jsx file
customers.jsx is the main file
In this the main code is there

```
<Route path="/data/:gender1"
       exact
       render={() => {
           return (
               <div >
                   <Customers2/>
               </div>
           );
       }}
/>
```

This is my `customers2.jsx` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    NavLink,
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

class Customers2 extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        console.log(this);
    }


    render() {
        console.log("ss" );
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>

            </div>            
        );
    }
}

export default Customers2;
```

If I go to localhost:3000/data/Male

In the console I don't see any props with the data
What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React extract param from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929784/react-extract-param-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route 
   path="/data/:gender1" 
   exact 
   render={props) => {
       return(
          <div>
            <Customers2 {...props} />
          </div>
        );
    }}
/>
```

You need to pass props of react-router down to the component as well.

Answer (score 0):

The props are passed from `render`, which you'd need to pass down explicitly:

```
<Route path="/data/:gender1" exact render={({match) => 
   <Customers2 gender={match.params.gender1} />
} />
```

See [the documentation on route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) and the [match object](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) for more information